# Handle Cell Editing in a Editable TableView in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I was created a Editable TableView, but don't know how to handle the cell data. For example, when user edit a cell and enter an empty string, how to alert them and set the field to old value?
I tried textField.getText().equals(""), but it doesn't work.

```
private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap() * 2);
        textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
                if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                    if (textField.getText().equals("")) {
                        cancelEdit();
                    }else commitEdit(textField.getText());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: The code seems ok. How did it not work?

Comment: Well I don't know why, that why I posted this question here. So this is my whole Netbeans Project. Can you check it please? Thanks you! http://upnhanh.mobi/get/Ovy1z

Answer (score 0):

By handling it immediately I guess you meant this

```
    textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent t) {
            if (textField.getText().equals("")) {
                cancelEdit();
            }
            else if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sory verymuch! I've updated the question. My example is: When user edit a cell and enter an empty string, how to alert them and set the field to old value?

Comment: @dangxunb then your code should work for keeping original text when new one is empty. Isn't it?